# Confusing Error in Bluej

Tags: runtime-error, bluej

When i run following it runs successfully :

```
import java.util.*;
public class god {
    public void main() {
        int chalnabey;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("t");
    }
}
```

But when i add another line to assign input to variable, the left side red loader goes non-stop progressing and my code never runs !

```
import java.util.*;
public class god {
    public void main() {
        int chalnabey;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        chalnabey=in.nextInt();               //This is addition line to previous code
        System.out.println("t");
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell why this happens and how to correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just waiting for input from the keyboard at the line

```
chalnabey = in.nextInt();
```

Open the BlueJ Terminal Window (from the main BlueJ menu, click View > Show Terminal) and you'll see the cursor flashing.  Type in any text and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and your program will continue executing.